# User Agent Alternative

Tags: mobile, browser, user-agent

How to detect mobile browser wothout using *user agent*?

Tried to find in net but all found links are abour *user agent*

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: you can't, at least on the server side.
But, more importantly, why would you want *not* to use the user agent string?

If you only want to detect whether the browser is mobile or not, I would do this using JavaScript, by simply guessing it given the screen size / resolution of the device.

Comment: it was question on interview.

Comment: The only other way I can think of, not precise at all though, would be to use HTTP Browser Fingerprinting. Every web browser may send, for example, headers in a different order. You can use this to detect the signature of a browser crawling your website, but I'm really not convinced.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you're doing it server-side or client-side. Server-side you're pretty much limited to UserAgent unless you do really custom stuff.

Client-side you could look at libraries like modernizer.js or yepnope.js. They may be using user agent data behind the scenes, not sure.

Of course if the browser has JavaScript disabled you're out of luck with that too.

Comment: I don't know about Modernizr. But, you're right, Yepnope uses browser-specific behaviors to detect it, like `window.opera` for Opera or `MozAppearance` for Gecko. On the client side...